# Why is Travis not recognising installed CMake in script?

Tags: cmake, travis-ci

I'm trying to put together a Travis CI script for my application, which requires CMake 3.5 or greater. The entire Travis script can be found [here](https://github.com/luntergroup/octopus/blob/exp/travis/.travis.yml). Following advice I found elsewhere, I use the following to install CMake:

```
 install:
    - DEPS_DIR="${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/deps"
    - mkdir -p ${DEPS_DIR} && cd ${DEPS_DIR}

    - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then
        CMAKE_URL="https://cmake.org/files/v3.7/cmake-3.7.2-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz";
        mkdir cmake && travis_retry wget --no-check-certificate --quiet -O - ${CMAKE_URL} | tar --strip-components=1 -xz -C cmake;
        export PATH=${DEPS_DIR}/cmake/bin:${PATH};
      else
        brew outdated cmake || brew upgrade cmake;
      fi
    - cmake --version
```

Then I fill out the build `matrix` with various OS/compiler combinations, and finally I run a Python installation script (see [here](https://github.com/luntergroup/octopus/blob/exp/travis/install.py)):

```
before_script:
    - cd "${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}"

script:
    - ./install.py --compiler=$COMPILER
```

The Python script essentially just calls `cmake` and `make`, the first `CMakeLists.txt` can be found [here](https://github.com/luntergroup/octopus/blob/exp/travis/CMakeLists.txt).

The OSX builds which install CMake using Homebrew works perfectly. However, all of the Linux builds fail at the `script` stage due to CMake not meeting the minimum requirement:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 3.5 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.2.2
```

Even though CMake 3.7 was successfully installed during `install`:

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.7.2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `export PATH=${DEPS_DIR}/cmake/bin:${PATH};` -- Python is by no means my forte; could it be that Python has its own ideas about sourcing PATH, perhaps for security reasons, and does not "see" your changed PATH? Let the Python script echo its PATH variable for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is strange, the preinstalled version of CMake (= v3.2 on Travis) is used instead of the newer one – but only when called from Python.

You can try these:

#### Solution 1: Remove the CMake shipped by Travis

This will prevent the usage of the older version. If this doesn't work (eg. maybe because "Cmake isn't found"), this will show the actual reason of the problem.

You can add this to your linux branch of the `install`  step:

```
sudo apt-get purge cmake
```

Or:

```
sudo apt-get remove cmake
```

(Possible you need to add `-y` for confirmation, so it becomes `remove -y`).

#### Solution 2: Use the CMake installer

Installation through the CMake Installer is a much cleaner way. It turned out the be the faster one on Travis btw.

```
...
- if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then
    CMAKE_INSTALLER=install-cmake.sh
    curl -sSL https://cmake.org/files/v3.7/cmake-3.7.2-Linux-x86_64.sh -o ${CMAKE_INSTALLER}
    chmod +x ${CMAKE_INSTALLER}
    sudo ./${CMAKE_INSTALLER} --prefix=/usr/local --skip-license
  else
    ...
```

I'm using *curl* instead of *wget + travis_retry*, but this doesn't matter. You can still use them as before.

---

If both don't work, you should check where the Python script looks for executables.